# How do I pass a string to a layout?

Tags: android, string, layout, transfer

I need to define this video ID but for some reason, I can't specify it programmatically like "loadVideo" or something. There is a problem with the lib, I'm trying to solve it as well but in case I can't solve it, I need to send a string to `app:videoId` dynamically. I can specify it with an XML file like `@string/video_id` but I can't change the XML file when the app is running. So it would be great if you could help me.

This is in my constraint layout

[image]

Comment: You can use databinding and pass in the string value to the LayoutBinding.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.myapp.data.ViewModel" />
    </data>
    <!-- UI layout's root element -->
    <ConstraintLayout... 
    app:videoID="@{viewmodel.videoID}"
    />
</Layout>
```

`YourFragment.kt`

```kotlin
findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.youtube_player).apply {
    videoID = "Your Video ID" 
}
```

References:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding
- https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-databinding